# Appinventor player stops when screen locks

Tags: android, app-inventor

When screen locked or app minimized, the "player 'UI component'" of appinventor stops playing.

I have tried reading relevant docs, but is it something not possible to do with appinventor?

Answer (score 1):

[There is this workaround](http://puravidaapps.com/countdown.php), which uses the video player component (but this does not work with all components), alternatively you can try [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/E-4qtjVUnRc/p35QTfquZqYJ) :

> use a timer 10 seconds to prompt empty notifier with no background
>   that will prevent your application from going to "sleep"

[Another possibility together with SL4a see here.](http://puravidaapps.com/countdown1.php)